# How to print 3D object to PDF from canvas app

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have a canvas app where my client uploads a 3D image and puts a few fins where needed. For reporting purposes I need to print a screenshot of the 3D image with the points where they can rotate the object and see the frontal, lateral and zenithal views in 3 boxes and print it to PDF.

The regular PDF print doesn't show 3D objects and displays a black rectangle and everything I search for online is catered towards mobile use, whereas my client only has access to the app via PC.

Has anyone found any solutions to this?